# What is my title?

Tags: title, role

I will be single-handedly running my mother's clinic over her 2-week vacation.  What would be my official job title, for resume's sake?

**Edit**: I am normally the **President** of the clinic -analyzing performance and implementing solutions (including coding custom software, running analytics, etc.)

This is an **OT/PT/SLP** clinic (i.e. **Occupational, Physical, and Speech Language Pathology Therapy**.)

Comment: What did your mother say when you asked her?

Comment: What does your contract say?

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't have a contract.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- She didn't have an answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere OT/PT/SLP clinic. I also happen to be the president, according to this https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/finding-a-job/president-vs-coo . I think the job fits the bill of COO.

Comment: @Sam, Does  **OT/PT/SLP**  stand for "**Occupational, Physical and Speech Language Therapy**" ?  If yes, then it must be super impressive for a 20 or 21 year old person to be the **president** of such a professional clinic as most workers there probably need a 4 year nursing degree or even a 10 year medical degree. If yes, then the title **president** alone is certainly super impressive enough for the resume .

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, I am normally the president -analyzing performance and implementing solutions (including coding custom software, running analytics, etc.) This is two weeks of extra responsibility out of a full time summer job.

Comment: @Sam, The title "**President**" and "**CEO**" are the 2 highest titles in any companies, organizations, or even countries. If you believe that you are already the "**President of the clinic**", then simply use that title in your resume to impress and **BLOW AWAY the mind of the resume reviewers**.  It does not make sense to be concerned about "**This two weeks of extra responsibility out of a full time summer job**". Best of luck, "**Mr. President of the clinic**".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere coding jobs.

Answer (score 2):

A two week job as managing director is a bit laughable on a resume especially if it's looking after your mothers business. Even more so if you don't actually work there already in some capacity.

If you do already work there then I'd put your job title and occasional acting director, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You're an **Acting Manager**.

You're not a director - an acting director doesn't make sense, and you probably need a medical degree.

You're not a CEO, there are no other "officers" to be chief of. You won't report to a board of directors.

Both executives and directors typically make high-level decisions. You will not be doing so in a 2 week period.

You're an Acting Manager.

The title also probably doesn't imply that you have some sort of certification that you don't have.

Comment: In his/her comment below the original question, the OP wrote that he/she is already the "President or COO of the clinic". Don't you think the title "**President/COO**" is more "**impressive**" than "**Acting Manager**" ? -- BTW, it is very interesting that the "President/COO" is running around asking people what his/her job title should be for the 2 weeks when his/her mom is on vacation. Just a thought... :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 The goal is to be accurate AND impressive. The OP calling themselves COO is already misleading.

Comment: @JOB_SEPTEMBER_2020 C level executives make high level decisions that the management hierarchy then acts on. I think more likely the OP just makes operational decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay- it’s your Mom’s clinic- you can put whatever you’d like on your resume, so long as she will back it up.! (This is assuming she owns the clinic and doesn’t just work there) I wouldn’t include that you only performed this role for 2 weeks. I also wouldn’t label yourself as president of the clinic or C— anything, ever, as that sounds silly considering it’s a clinic. You can inflate your title all you want, but employers aren’t idiots. Also, I believe clinical directors are always medical degree holders, so unless you’re an MD its clearly an inflated job title. And president and COO both are ridiculous considering your lack of a degree and age, to a prospective employer. I am a nurse, and I have worked as a manager in a clinic, this is why I feel my advice is relevant. I would label yourself as clinic manager for the entirety of your summer term and possibly stretch those dates even further to show continuous employment, not just a summer position, which will be easily identifiable by any employer looking at the resume of a college student, esp if the clinic has your own name in it (showing you’re clearly working for family, which doesn’t earn the same respect as getting the same position somewhere else) I hope this helped any.

Answer (score 0):

For a two-week period covering a vacation your job title **doesn't change**. What has changed (temporarily) are your duties - if you want to highlight that you've occasionally done things that are outside of your normal role e.g. on a CV then you would describe that you've done them in your description of the job.

Answer (score -2):

Your title is whatever your mother's title is, prepended by "Acting".

E.g. If your mother is the "Director" then you are the "Acting Director".

If your mother does not use a title for herself, give her one. Make it as lofty as the job will support, without getting silly. Get her permission to call her by that title.

Then call yourself the "Acting <mother's new title>".

Comment: What would be an appropriate title for her? CEO? Executive manager? I am thinking based on (this article)[https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/business-hierarchy#:~:text=What%20are%20the%20different%20levels%20in%20a%20business,...%206%20Vice%20president.%20...%20More%20items...%20] that the most appropriate titles are president and COO.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no transfer of ownership happened.